# Is the diphthong /aʊ/ generally realized as [ɑʊ] in British English?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, vowels, diphthongs

I noticed that the diphthong **/aʊ/** is pronounced by most British English speakers as **[ɑʊ]** (I may be inaccurate here).

You can see the vowel /a/ on the [vowel diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_diagram) below:

> > [image: Vowel Chart]

I understand this diagram quite well and the vowel /a/ is located at left bottom, so when I pronounce the diphthong /aʊ/ with the vowel /a/ (as shown in the diagram), it doesn't sound like the one pronounced by native British English speakers at all. But when I pronounce the diphthong /aʊ/ with the BATH vowel (Southern British English *BATH*: /ɑː/), it sounds quite normal.

Also listen to the following YouTube videos you will observe:

- ["f**ou**nd **ou**t ab**ou**t her"](https://youtu.be/51KUocErpj0?t=62)
- ["ab**ou**t"](https://youtu.be/F8Rwz3KWFHA?t=242)
- ["r**ou**nd ab**ou**t"](https://youtu.be/kh7bv7tLRlc?t=2495)

(copied with exact time)

**Is the diphthong /aʊ/ generally realized as [ɑʊ] in Southern British English (also called "Modern RP")?** (I would also be interested to know how American speakers pronounce it generally.)

Comment: I am also unsure about the vowel /ʊ/. I don't know if it is realized  exactly as [ʊ] or something else but that is a completely different question, I guess.

Comment: 'Bath' is pronounced in a number of different ways in Britain.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I think the OP is referring to RP, they've added '/ɑ/' with 'British BATH' ('British BATH: **/ɑ/**').

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) says that "conservative RP" realizes it as [ɑʊ], and "contemporary RP" realizes it as [aʊ]. So you clearly can hear it realized both ways. There are many, many more dialects of British English than these, and I don't think it's "generally realized" in just one way.

Comment: In no dialect of English are /a/ and /ɑ/ distinct phonemes.

Comment: @tchrist What about RP "ban" /ban/ and "barn" /bɑːn/? Aren't they distinct phonemes now? Does vowel length (/ɑː/) count as phonemic?

Comment: Prof. Uta-Frith is not a native English speaker and her German accent can be easily heard. Prof. Brian Cox was born in Oldham and speaks with a pronounced Oldham accent. In short - neither speaks RP nor is their accent at all "typical".

Comment: It may be worth noting that in a Sussex accent (can't really get more Southern British), words written "ou" are pronounced [øu].

Answer (score 0):

Peter Shor commented:

> [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) says that "conservative RP" realizes it as [ɑʊ], and "contemporary RP" realizes it as [aʊ]. So you clearly can hear it realized both ways. There are many, many more dialects of British English than these, and I don't think it's "generally realized" in just one way.